# Hibernate works but not when invoked through web service

Tags: hibernate, tomcat

I got a method that uses hibernate to connect to DB and retrieve the data. The method works fine when executed as standalone java app. However when I try to deploy it on tomcat and invoke as a web service I get an error as below. My method is the first and the only place where DB connection is being established, i.e. I'm not defining any datasources within tomcat.

```
No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation 
of non-transactional one here
at
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(LocalSessionFactoryBean.
```

My hibernate config file:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.statement_cache.size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</prop>                
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${mydbSchema}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>        
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup</prop>                
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm using the following hibernate modules:

hibernate-annotations 3.4.0.GA,
hibernate-core 3.3.1.GA,
hibernate 3.2.6.ga,
hibernate-commons-annotations 3.1.0.GA

Comment: What are you doing to manage the Hibernate session for the web service calls?

Comment: Not sure I understand but maybe I should :). I'm using spring and got the data source and the session factory defined as spring beans. Is that what you are asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs to be called in a transaction.   Or your method needs to use a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If the class implementing server-side web-service is a Spring bean, simply surround method accessing the database with `@Transactional`. If this is not the case, add that annotation to some other Spring bean that works as an intermediary between WS and DAO.

If `@Transactional` does not work for you, you can always use [`TransactionTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html).

Comment: Eric, Tomasz - I get this error right when I call getCurrentSession() on the SessionFactory object. So I cannot even create a session. And I can't create a transaction without a session.